# How To Remove .cgi From URL With .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server, url-rewriting, cgi

I use a .cgi file to run python on my server. However, whenever someone goes to the site, it brings them to https://example.com/main.cgi/ (main.cgi is the name of the cgi file). Is there a way to remove this from the .htacess file, so it goes to https://example.com/ but still runs the cgi file?

This is the current .cgi file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /website

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main.cgi/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

How can I make a `RewriteRule` that makes the URL `/` go to `/main.cgi/` without it appearing in the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make your https implementation as a first rule of your .htaccess file, could you please try following. Written as per your shown samples, please make sure you clear your cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rule for applying https to non-http calls.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

##Look for if any page doesn't have `/`slashes at the end then add it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

##Rules for non exiting file or directory to main.cgi file.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ main.cgi [L]
```

***NOTE:*** Using `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]` personally gives me 1 slash at end so I had written a separate rule for adding trailing `/` for this one, to avoid 2 times `/` at the end of url.